# How to enable CORS in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I use this fetchData config in React.js:

```
fetchData = () => {
      fetch("http://localhost:8000/batch_predict", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" // otherwise $_POST is empty
        },
      ,
    body: JSON.stringify({
      holdingTime: this.state.holdingTime,
      csvData: this.state.csvData
    })
  })
  .then((resp) => {
    return resp.json()
  })
  .then((data) => {
    this.updateDelay(data.prediction)
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
  })
```

};

It sends well the data, however I get CORS error.

If I set headers as follows, I do not get CORS error, but the data is set wrongly:

```
 headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 }
```

Therefore I want to maintain the first option, but how can I enable CORS in this case?

In Django backend `settings.py` I added all the CORS related lines:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: try using  `application/jsonp` rather than `application/json` -- I think that will also allow you to  bypass the CORS thing.

Comment: in the attached settings.py I can't see anything added for CORS, can you specify what you added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OPTION request the server should indicate, that it actually allows cross site requests but expects credentials to be sent. This is done by the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true response header which can be set up by using the djang-cors-headers package.

```
pip3 install django-cors-headers
```

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:3000',
)
```

Reference: https://medium.com/@zoltankohalmy/react-and-django-57f949b0f012

Comment: What is `myapp`?

Comment: That's just added to show you as an example. It should be your app. But you should have `corsheaders` in installed apps.